# why the order of labeling changes when I use lab row in heatmap and how to avoid overlapping

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a data way much larger than the following

```
df<- structure(c(14.12087951, 14.99460661, 33.46234987, 10.17615856, 
5.274590779, 2262.260928, 30.95475607, 489.3857185, 100.2231956, 
1.927758832, 12063.47923, 12.40706075, 2010.075103, 1161.375364, 
789.7376463, 3118.915801, 202.9969196, 5.098794774, 913.8294948, 
25.66624202, 254.0262357, 351.1804779, 1.164233553, 1.725950597, 
1.73866603, -0.182861618, 1.073288641, 2.355917497, 1.903814342, 
2.106296918, 1.641698736, 1.00452836, 1.530285115, 1.224115304, 
1.549014357, 1.571649698, 1.336788511, 1.566214154, 1.287767608, 
1.43739379, 1.107868132, 1.446075949, 1.053322707, 1.084792083
), .Dim = c(22L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "AAA", "AAAA", 
"AAAAA", "AAAAAA", "AAAAAAA", "B", "BB", "BBB", "BBBB", "BBBBB", 
"F", "FFF", "FFFFF", "FFFFFF", "FFFFFFF", "FFFFFFFF", "E62534", 
"GDTDFS", "AZE", "ZIEY", "SIS"), c("value1", "value2")))
```

I am trying to show only specific labels when I use heatmap.2
So I do this

```
Labelst <- c("BBBBB", "AAAAAAA", "SIS","ZIEY")
heatmap.2(df, labRow = Labelst)
```

Is I don't use the labRow, then the order of the labels are different. for example, compare the following with above

```
heatmap.2(df)
```

Now, biggest issue is how to avoid overlapping? when I have 1000 of rows, then when I try to show only specific ones, they overlap. Can someone show me how to show specific row labeles with a flash ? or with a distance from each other? I don't want to change the font and make it smaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure read the help page of `heatmap.2` as it's very detailed. While not specifically stated, `labRow` takes a vector of the same length as your data.frame. The help states `these default to rownames(x)`.

So simply replace any labels you don't want with an empty string.

```
have <- rownames(df)
want <- c("BBBBB", "AAAAAAA", "SIS","ZIEY")
have[!(have %in% want)] <- ""
heatmap.2(df, labRow = have)
```

I missed the second half of your question. The options avaliable for heatmap.2 to modify/change the row/colnames are these:

```
       # Row/Column Labeling
       margins = c(5, 5),
       ColSideColors,
       RowSideColors,
       cexRow = 0.2 + 1/log10(nr),
       cexCol = 0.2 + 1/log10(nc),
       labRow = NULL,
       labCol = NULL,
       srtRow = NULL,
       srtCol = NULL,
       adjRow = c(0,NA),
       adjCol = c(NA,0),
       offsetRow = 0.5,
       offsetCol = 0.5,
       colRow = NULL,
       colCol = NULL,
```

Note specifically `cexRow`, it specifies the size. Change this variable to stop overlapping.

Comment: thanks , I will accept your answer, however, do you mind to add something else ? the second part is that , when the row names are overlapped, I want to avoid any overlap on the naming, so is there a possibility to add an arrow to each name and then put them under each other ?

Comment: That's not possible with `heatmap.2` function. It's probably possible with some long winded hack but not natively. Try messing with `srtRow` `srtCol` and see if that helps. 

The other option is to increase the size of the canvas you are saving to. This might fix the issue as well.